# How to use TemplateSelector for Xamarin Forms TemplatedView?

Tags: forms, xamarin, controltemplate

I need to use a TemplateSelector for the ControlTemplate in TemplatedView. Is there any way to handle ControlTemplateSelector, similar to how DataTemplateSelector is done?

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>   
        <data:MediaTemplateSelector x:Key="headerTemplateSelector"
                    VideoTemplate="{StaticResource VideoHeaderTemplate}"
                    ImageTemplate="{StaticResource ImageHeaderTemplate}" /> 
    </ResourceDictionary> 
</ContentPage.Resources> 
<ContentPage.Content>
    <TemplatedView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplateSelector}"/> 
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: You could use control templates.It provides a clean separation between the appearance of a page and its content, enabling the creation of pages that can easily be themed. Here is a similar thread which maybe can help you https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/84810/datatemplates-and-contentcontrols

Answer (score 1):

ControlTemplate and DataTemplate works in a different manner.

I started with ControlTemplates trying to do something similar to DataTemplateSelector but defining an item appearance at page level instead at item in a collection like a ListView or CollectionView. So confusing at the beginning because it works totally different... first: forget the concept of DataTempateSelector, has nothing to do with ControlTemplates.

The code i will present has some properties/class names in spanish, hope you understand the idea anyway. First, suppose you have a property on your ViewModel that needs to be presented in a different manner depending on the same or other ViewModel property.

First, define a ContentView class that later you will put as a part of your page (could be a TemplatedView, but, i'm getting an exception when i try to put the templatedView directly on a page, so, i use a ContentView):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:MrWaiter.Resources;assembly=MrWaiter"
             x:Class="MrWaiter.Views.ComandaControlTemplate"
             ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ComandaPropia}">

    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate  x:Key="ComandaPropia">
            <Frame   BackgroundColor="{x:StaticResource Key=pLight}" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="True" HeightRequest="32"
                       Padding="0" Margin="0">

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    <Label FontSize="Large" 
                               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                               TextColor="White"
                               Margin="5,0,0,0"
                               BindingContext="{TemplateBinding BindingContext}"
                               Text="{TemplateBinding Parent.BindingContext.Comanda.Numero, StringFormat='Comanda {0}'}">
                            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="2"
                                      BindingContext="{TemplateBinding BindingContext}"                 
                                   Command="{TemplateBinding Parent.BindingContext.MostrarComandasCommand}"            >
                                </TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Label>

                    <Button FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}" 
                                 HorizontalOptions="End" x:Name="botonExpandir" 
                                Text="{x:Static local1:IconFont.Play}"     BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                                Rotation="-90" FontSize="32"  TextColor="White" 
                                WidthRequest="55"
                                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                Padding="0,0,0,0"
                                Command="{TemplateBinding MaximizeCommand}"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                >

                    </Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComandaInvitaA" >
            <Frame   BackgroundColor="DarkGray" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="True" HeightRequest="32"
                       Padding="0" Margin="0">

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    <Label FontSize="Large" 


                               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                               TextColor="White"
                               Margin="5,0,0,0"
                               BindingContext="{TemplateBinding BindingContext}"
                               Text="{TemplateBinding Parent.BindingContext.Comanda.Numero, StringFormat='Comanda {0}'}">
                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="2"
                                      BindingContext="{TemplateBinding BindingContext}"                 
                                   Command="{TemplateBinding Parent.BindingContext.MostrarComandasCommand}"            >
                            </TapGestureRecognizer>
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>

                    </Label>

                    <Button FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}" 
                                 HorizontalOptions="End" x:Name="botonExpandir" x:FieldModifier="Public"
                                Text="{x:Static local1:IconFont.Play}"    BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                                Rotation="-90" FontSize="32"  TextColor="White" 
                                WidthRequest="55"
                                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                Padding="0,0,0,0"
                           BindingContext="{TemplateBinding BindingContext}" 
                                Command="{TemplateBinding Parent.BindingContext.MaximizeCommand}"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                >

                    </Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComandaInvitadaPor">
            <Frame   BackgroundColor="{x:StaticResource Key=sColor}" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="True" HeightRequest="32"
                       Padding="0" Margin="0">

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    <Label FontSize="Large" 
                               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                               TextColor="White"
                               Margin="5,0,0,0"
                              BindingContext="{TemplateBinding BindingContext}"
                               Text="{TemplateBinding Parent.BindingContext.Comanda.Numero, StringFormat='Comanda {0}'}">
                            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="2"
                                      BindingContext="{TemplateBinding BindingContext}"                 
                                   Command="{TemplateBinding Parent.BindingContext.MostrarComandasCommand}"            >
                                </TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Label>
                    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding MostrarDetallado}"
                                IsVisible="False"
                                OnColor="{StaticResource Key=sLight}"
                                ThumbColor="{StaticResource Key=sDark}"
                                ></Switch>
                    <Button FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}" 
                                 HorizontalOptions="End" x:Name="botonExpandir" 
                                Text="{x:Static local1:IconFont.Play}"     BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                                Rotation="-90" FontSize="32"  TextColor="White" 
                                WidthRequest="55"
                                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                Padding="0,0,0,0"
                                Command="{TemplateBinding MaximizeCommand}"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                >

                    </Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </ControlTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentView.Resources>

</ContentView>
```

The important stuff is this property of contentView, that defines a kind of ControlTemplate default value:

```
ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ComandaPropia}"
```

And pay attention on how the Data Binding is defined inside the ControlTemplates, using TemplatedBindings instead Bindings:

```
 <Label FontSize="Large" 
                               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                               TextColor="White"
                               Margin="5,0,0,0"
                               BindingContext="{TemplateBinding BindingContext}"
                               Text="{TemplateBinding Parent.BindingContext.Comanda.Numero, StringFormat='Comanda {0}'}">
```

On the ContentView Code Behind you must create a BindableProperty to allow DataBinding between a property on View and a property on ViewModel  (maybe it could be done with DataTriggers, but im's learning Xamaring and i want to practice with BindableProperties). That Property, will be responsible to select the ControlTemplate, pay attention to Method HandleTipoComandaPropertyChanged, its where we select the ControlTemplate on propertyChanged:

```
  public partial class ComandaControlTemplate : ContentView
    {
        public static BindableProperty TipoComandaProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "TipoComanda",
            returnType: typeof(Controls.TipoComandaEnum),
            declaringType: typeof(ComandaControlTemplate),
            defaultValue: Controls.TipoComandaEnum.Propia,
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: HandleTipoComandaPropertyChanged);

        private static void HandleTipoComandaPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var targetView = (ComandaControlTemplate)bindable;

            if (targetView != null)
            {
                if ((Controls.TipoComandaEnum)newValue != (Controls.TipoComandaEnum)oldValue)
                {
                    if ((Controls.TipoComandaEnum)newValue== Controls.TipoComandaEnum.Propia)
                        targetView.ControlTemplate =(ControlTemplate)targetView.Resources["ComandaPropia"];
                    else if ((Controls.TipoComandaEnum)newValue == Controls.TipoComandaEnum.Invitada)
                        targetView.ControlTemplate = (ControlTemplate)targetView.Resources["ComandaInvitadaPor"];
                    else if ((Controls.TipoComandaEnum)newValue == Controls.TipoComandaEnum.Invitacion)

                }
            }
        }



        public Controls.TipoComandaEnum TipoComanda
        {

            get
            {
                return Controls.TipoComandaEnum)base.GetValue(TipoComandaProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                    base.SetValue(TipoComandaProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public ComandaControlTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Finally, in your page, place your templated ContentView whenever you need and bind the BindableProperty we created in View to the property on ViewModel that will determine the ControlTemplate presented:

```
<views:ComandaControlTemplate TipoComanda="{Binding BindingContext.TipoComanda}"></views:ComandaControlTemplate>
```

Note that TipoComanda is the BindableProperty we created on templatedView, and it as an equivalent property on ViewModel.

Note: that's a general idea on how can we use ControlTemplates, it works, but maybe there are better ways to acomplish.